# How can I update a html file that is uploaded in a remote site?

Tags: html, ftp, remote-server

This is a very general question, because I have not even started to implement anything and I am still in the brainstorming stage.
I have the following situation:

There is a remote site to which I upload through FTP several HTML files *periodically* (The generation and upload of these HTML files is done through a python script that I've created).

The number of these files is increasing and ideally I would like to have an index-type of HTML file on the remote location. This file of course should get updated with a new entry everytime I upload the data HTML files.

Is there a way to do this, other than downloading this index html, updating it and uploading it again?

Perhaps something running on the remote location that detects the uploading and updates the index?

I am hopping someone give me a push in the right direction so that I can then research how to do it on my own and perhaps come with more concrete questions

Answer (score 0):

You could have a script that scans for files, gets a list of filenames and then automatically generates the html file. Have that running periodically via a cron job. Without more info I can't really give any more advice past that.

Edit: you can also use [incron](https://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab) to monitor directories just have a watch on the directory/* with IN_MODIFY flag (and IN_DELETE if needed) and a watch on the directory with IN_CREATE flag, I can't seem to get multiple flags working, might have to manually or the flags but I can't find their binary values either

inotify could also be used in a script but this seems much simpler

Comment: Thanks. So I guess the first time I have to look for is cron jobs. Is it possible with this to "detect" when an upload is done to update the index immediately or should it has to be just periodically?

Comment: it is possible to use with incron, after installing with sudo apt-get install incron add yourself to the allow file in /etc/incron.allow and then setup a directory watch with

/path/*     IN_MODIFY       action

/path/      IN_CREATE       action